# SVG files render differently in browsers - typography

Tags: website-design, svg, web-fonts, web-safe

I have a problem with svg backgrounds that render differently in browsers.In Chrome the letters are correctly gill sans light and two words are bold. That's not the case in Firefox. How do I fix this, so it looks like in Chrome across all browsers?

Also - they appear FPS-heavy even though the files are under 1kb. Why is this?

site: http://www.teamgenerous.com

Browsers: newest versions

[image: different rendring Chrome and Firefox]

Thank you

Comment: Don't you to convert text to outlines before save?

Comment: Have played with Adobe CEF/SVG with and without subset.. no results in Firefox. Only the outline works.

Comment: See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905026/cross-browser-embedded-font-in-svg-image

Comment: @Vnovak you could, but then lose the benefit of having text in the SVG from an accessibility/SEO standpoint.

Comment: looks like font need to be hosted at the same host as page.. and it more looks like embedding of font to website. I am not sure, but it can rise copyright issues and will require separate license (similar to web font usage). If so, simpler to run font as web font instead SVG. Can be wrong ;)

Comment: Just a FYI: it looks even more broken on my Linux FF 30.0 http://imgur.com/qolLXDd

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is a known "wontfix" bug with Firefox not fully supporting SVG fonts. Once WOFF2 becomes fully supported, Firefox will render SVG font outlines embedded in an OpenType-flavored WOFF 2 font. At least that's the idea. Learn more here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119490

Answer (score 0):

because each browser has a default font, for render it, you shall use css normalize like [it library](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssfonts/) , or disable default font with javascript and css